# Linking Shared Drive Document URL in Custom List

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, hyperlink

Problem - Trying to add a URL to a document that is located on a shared drive to a custom list.  When I add the link to a custom list (i.e. file//W://file/.../.pdf) it lets me add the link but after I save the link is no longer there.

I found many solutions for problems with using a wiki page adding a link to a document that is located on a shared drive but nothing for a custom list.  If I'm able to add a url to a website and document saved on SharePoint shouldn't I be able to do the same using a shared drive document to a custom list.

Answer (score 1):

We link to network shared resources a lot and the addresses stay put in a URL field in a list

While we prefer not to use the mapped drive name in our environment (not everyone might have the same drive mapped), it does work like you've got.

Make sure it's structured correctly - after you type it in, does it come up when you click the 'test this link'?

Also make sure it's structured as file://W:..... - I'm assuming you have a typo in your question - remember the colon after the file.

Try not using the mapped drive name and using the actual directory - file://cifs1/folder/folder/file.ext

I've also found sometimes that the / are being escaped out - especially if you are programmatically setting the field. For grins, you might try entering file:///W: and/or doubling up the / between the folders - I've never figured out the why, but sometimes if I fuss with the number of / I can get it to work. That a 'if all else fails try this'. An example - in this I'm getting rid of the O drive reference and putting it back to folders - in this case the mapped drive isn't universal to all.
Now I wrote this for 2010 so I'm not sure if it's necessary, but thought I'd throw it out there if you were setting the field via javascript.

```
if(pastethis.substring(0,2)== 'O:') {

                pastethis = "file:////\\\\cifs1\\folder1\\folder2" + pastethis.substring(2);
                } else {
                    pastethis = "file:////" + pastethis;
                }
```

And remember these links will only work in IE, not Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! I copied and paste directly from a wiki page where the links are working, They are not working in the list.  Is it the list?  Should I not copy and paste from a wiki page (where again it works) to a list?  Made sure the slashes were in the right place.

Comment: Hard to tell. I tested a link on a wiki page that was coded as \\cifs1\users\name\My Documents\folder\anotherfolder\anotherfolder. I copied that to a list directly and saved the item. It changed it to file://cifs1/users/name/My Documents/folder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder - it added the file: and reversed the slashes. Not sure what is going on with yours, sorry...